# for loop to select a particular row with a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, syntax

I would like to create a loop that reads the dataframe line by line of column `batch`. You can see the column `batch` values repeats after sometime (10,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,5......)

Now I am supposed to save a whole row value when a batch is completed. For example, the batch 10 completes at `2017-11-01 06:09:00    10       36 2775.430 70.20428 15.79604` and i want this saved to a new dataframe. Batch 1 completes at `2017-11-01 06:54:00     1       35 2781.480 70.49287 15.79604` and this needs to be saved and batch 2 completes at `2017-11-01 08:24:00     2       36 2782.080 69.56226 15.98735`, this wants to be saved .. and so on.

Any advice how i could write this?

```
             event_time   batch  duration   size       TP       YU
1    2017-11-01 05:34:00    10       36 2041.761 68.69974 15.79604
2    2017-11-01 05:39:00    10       36 2230.944 68.69974 15.79604
3    2017-11-01 05:44:00    10       36 2393.590 68.69974 15.79604
4    2017-11-01 05:49:00    10       36 2462.384 59.76005 15.79604
5    2017-11-01 05:54:00    10       36 2462.384 64.85409 15.79604
6    2017-11-01 05:59:00    10       36 2721.387 70.20428 15.79604
7    2017-11-01 06:04:00    10       36 2721.387 70.20428 15.79604
8    2017-11-01 06:09:00    10       36 2775.430 70.20428 15.79604
9    2017-11-01 06:14:00     1       35  103.060 70.20428  0.00000
10   2017-11-01 06:19:00     1       35 2237.591 70.20428 15.79604
11   2017-11-01 06:24:00     1       35 2237.591 70.20428 15.79604
12   2017-11-01 06:29:00     1       35 2399.109 70.20428 15.79604
13   2017-11-01 06:34:00     1       35 2467.942 60.56096 15.79604
14   2017-11-01 06:39:00     1       35 2467.942 65.68742 15.79604
15   2017-11-01 06:44:00     1       35 2726.943 70.49287 15.79604
16   2017-11-01 06:49:00     1       35 2726.943 70.49287 15.79604
17   2017-11-01 06:54:00     1       35 2781.480 70.49287 15.79604
18   2017-11-01 06:59:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
19   2017-11-01 07:04:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
20   2017-11-01 07:09:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
21   2017-11-01 07:14:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
22   2017-11-01 07:19:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
23   2017-11-01 07:24:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
24   2017-11-01 07:29:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
25   2017-11-01 07:34:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
26   2017-11-01 07:39:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
27   2017-11-01 07:44:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
28   2017-11-01 07:49:00     2       36  103.060 70.49287  0.00000
29   2017-11-01 07:54:00     2       36 2236.194 70.49287 15.98735
30   2017-11-01 07:59:00     2       36 2399.229 70.49287 15.98735
31   2017-11-01 08:04:00     2       36 2468.023 55.81712 15.98735
32   2017-11-01 08:09:00     2       36 2468.023 59.34176 15.98735
33   2017-11-01 08:14:00     2       36 2727.026 69.56226 15.98735
34   2017-11-01 08:19:00     2       36 2727.026 69.56226 15.98735
35   2017-11-01 08:24:00     2       36 2782.080 69.56226 15.98735
36   2017-11-01 08:29:00     3       34  103.060 69.56226  0.00000
37   2017-11-01 08:34:00     3       34  103.060 69.56226  0.00000
38   2017-11-01 08:39:00     3       34 2231.033 69.56226 15.89170
39   2017-11-01 08:44:00     3       34 2392.901 69.56226 15.89170
40   2017-11-01 08:49:00     3       34 2461.345 60.88197 15.89170
41   2017-11-01 08:54:00     3       34 2461.345 60.88197 15.89170
42   2017-11-01 08:59:00     3       34 2720.346 70.81388 15.89170
43   2017-11-01 09:04:00     3       34 2720.346 70.81388 15.89170
44   2017-11-01 09:09:00     3       34 2774.288 70.81388 15.89170
45   2017-11-01 09:14:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
46   2017-11-01 09:19:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
47   2017-11-01 09:24:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
48   2017-11-01 09:29:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
49   2017-11-01 09:34:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
50   2017-11-01 09:39:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
51   2017-11-01 09:44:00     4       36  103.060 70.81388  0.00000
52   2017-11-01 09:49:00     4       36 2226.752 70.81388 15.98735
53   2017-11-01 09:54:00     4       36 2455.156 70.81388 15.98735
54   2017-11-01 09:59:00     4       36 2455.156 56.55642 15.98735
55   2017-11-01 10:04:00     4       36 2455.156 56.55642 15.98735
56   2017-11-01 10:09:00     4       36 2455.156 68.57004 15.98735
57   2017-11-01 10:14:00     4       36 2714.158 69.78924 15.98735
58   2017-11-01 10:19:00     4       36 2714.158 69.78924 15.98735
59   2017-11-01 10:24:00     5       37  103.060 69.78924  0.00000
60   2017-11-01 10:29:00     5       37 2227.467 69.78924 15.89170
61   2017-11-01 10:34:00     5       37 2389.723 69.78924 15.89170
62   2017-11-01 10:39:00     5       37 2389.723 69.78924 15.89170
63   2017-11-01 10:44:00     5       37 2457.778 69.78924 15.89170
64   2017-11-01 10:49:00     5       37 2457.778 57.93126 15.89170
65   2017-11-01 10:54:00     5       37 2457.778 66.80934 15.89170
66   2017-11-01 10:59:00     5       37 2716.779 70.52529 15.89170
67   2017-11-01 11:04:00     5       37 2716.779 70.52529 15.89170
68   2017-11-01 11:09:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
69   2017-11-01 11:14:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
70   2017-11-01 11:19:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
71   2017-11-01 11:24:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
72   2017-11-01 11:29:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
73   2017-11-01 11:34:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
74   2017-11-01 11:39:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
75   2017-11-01 11:44:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
76   2017-11-01 11:49:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
77   2017-11-01 11:54:00     6       40  103.060 70.52529  0.00000
78   2017-11-01 11:59:00     6       40 2241.928 70.52529 15.89170
79   2017-11-01 12:04:00     6       40 2241.928 70.52529 15.89170
80   2017-11-01 12:09:00     6       40 2471.500 57.51621 15.89170
81   2017-11-01 12:14:00     6       40 2471.500 59.79248 15.89170
82   2017-11-01 12:19:00     6       40 2730.503 70.46044 15.89170
83   2017-11-01 12:24:00     6       40 2730.503 70.46044 15.89170
84   2017-11-01 12:29:00     6       40 2784.518 70.46044 15.89170
85   2017-11-01 12:34:00     7       32  103.060 70.46044  0.00000
86   2017-11-01 12:39:00     7       32  103.060 70.46044  0.00000
87   2017-11-01 12:44:00     7       32 2228.652 70.46044 15.81226
89   2017-11-01 12:54:00     7       32 2459.002 62.45136 15.81226
90   2017-11-01 12:59:00     7       32 2459.002 66.39105 15.81226
91   2017-11-01 13:04:00     7       32 2718.004 71.96498 15.81226
92   2017-11-01 13:09:00     7       32 2718.004 71.96498 15.81226
93   2017-11-01 13:14:00     7       32 2771.915 71.96498 15.81226
94   2017-11-01 13:19:00     8       33  103.060 71.96498  0.00000
95   2017-11-01 13:24:00     8       33 2237.687 71.96498 15.89170
96   2017-11-01 13:29:00     8       33 2469.166 71.96498 15.89170
97   2017-11-01 13:34:00     8       33 2469.166 62.80156 15.89170
98   2017-11-01 13:39:00     8       33 2469.166 66.29378 15.89170
99   2017-11-01 13:44:00     8       33 2728.167 70.87549 15.89170
100  2017-11-01 13:49:00     8       33 2728.167 70.87549 15.89170
101  2017-11-01 13:54:00     9       34  103.060 70.87549  0.00000
102  2017-11-01 13:59:00     9       34  103.060 70.87549  0.00000
103  2017-11-01 14:04:00     9       34  103.060 70.87549  0.00000
104  2017-11-01 14:09:00     9       34  103.060 70.87549  0.00000
105  2017-11-01 14:14:00     9       34  103.060 70.87549  0.00000
106  2017-11-01 14:19:00     9       34 2045.649 70.87549 15.98735
107  2017-11-01 14:24:00     9       34 2234.832 70.87549 15.98735
108  2017-11-01 14:29:00     9       34 2460.513 60.75227 15.98735
109  2017-11-01 14:34:00     9       34 2460.513 60.75227 15.98735
110  2017-11-01 14:39:00     9       34 2719.514 71.99741 15.98735
111  2017-11-01 14:44:00     9       34 2719.514 72.06226 15.98735
112  2017-11-01 14:49:00     9       34 2719.514 72.06226 15.98735
113  2017-11-01 14:54:00     1       32  103.060 72.06226  0.00000
114  2017-11-01 14:59:00     1       32  103.060 72.06226  0.00000
115  2017-11-01 15:04:00     1       32 2232.300 72.06226 15.79604
116  2017-11-01 15:09:00     1       32 2459.926 64.69196 15.79604
117  2017-11-01 15:14:00     1       32 2459.926 64.69196 15.79604
118  2017-11-01 15:19:00     1       32 2718.928 72.06226 15.79604
119  2017-11-01 15:24:00     1       32 2718.928 72.63943 15.79604
120  2017-11-01 15:29:00     1       32 2718.928 72.63943 15.79604
121  2017-11-01 15:34:00     2       32  103.060 72.63943  0.00000
122  2017-11-01 15:39:00     2       32  103.060 72.63943  0.00000
123  2017-11-01 15:44:00     2       32 2233.733 72.63943 15.79604
124  2017-11-01 15:49:00     2       32 2462.099 64.50065 15.79604
125  2017-11-01 15:54:00     2       32 2462.099 64.53307 15.79604
126  2017-11-01 15:59:00     2       32 2721.101 71.93580 15.79604
127  2017-11-01 16:04:00     2       32 2721.101 72.67185 15.79604
128  2017-11-01 16:09:00     2       32 2721.101 72.67185 15.79604
129  2017-11-01 16:14:00     3       33  103.060 72.67185  0.00000
130  2017-11-01 16:19:00     3       33  103.060 72.67185  0.00000
131  2017-11-01 16:24:00     3       33  103.060 72.67185  0.00000
132  2017-11-01 16:29:00     3       33  103.060 72.67185  0.00000
133  2017-11-01 16:34:00     3       33 2233.003 72.67185 15.98735
134  2017-11-01 16:39:00     3       33 2394.871 72.67185 15.98735
135  2017-11-01 16:44:00     3       33 2462.536 62.22763 15.98735
136  2017-11-01 16:49:00     3       33 2462.536 68.21660 15.98735
137  2017-11-01 16:54:00     3       33 2721.537 72.22438 15.98735
138  2017-11-01 16:59:00     3       33 2721.537 72.22438 15.98735
139  2017-11-01 17:04:00     3       33 2775.676 72.22438 15.98735
140  2017-11-01 17:09:00     4       33 2232.340 72.22438 15.60311
141  2017-11-01 17:14:00     4       33 2392.301 72.22438 15.60311
142  2017-11-01 17:19:00     4       33 2460.356 65.71984 15.60311
143  2017-11-01 17:24:00     4       33 2460.356 66.03761 15.60311
144  2017-11-01 17:29:00     4       33 2719.357 73.50519 15.60311
145  2017-11-01 17:34:00     4       33 2719.357 73.50519 15.60311
146  2017-11-01 17:39:00     4       33 2719.357 73.50519 15.60311
147  2017-11-01 17:44:00     5       36  103.060 73.50519  0.00000
148  2017-11-01 17:49:00     5       36 1909.972 73.50519 15.79604
149  2017-11-01 17:54:00     5       36 2239.077 73.50519 15.79604
150  2017-11-01 17:59:00     5       36 2471.684 65.07782 15.79604
151  2017-11-01 18:04:00     5       36 2471.684 65.07782 15.79604
152  2017-11-01 18:09:00     5       36 2730.686 72.63943 15.79604
153  2017-11-01 18:14:00     5       36 2730.686 73.34306 15.79604
154  2017-11-01 18:19:00     5       36 2730.686 73.34306 15.79604
155  2017-11-01 18:24:00     5       36 2785.718 73.34306 15.79604
156  2017-11-01 18:29:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
157  2017-11-01 18:34:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
158  2017-11-01 18:39:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
159  2017-11-01 18:44:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
160  2017-11-01 18:49:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
161  2017-11-01 18:54:00     6       38  103.060 73.34306  0.00000
162  2017-11-01 18:59:00     6       38 2222.261 73.34306 16.10084
163  2017-11-01 19:04:00     6       38 2453.739 73.34306 16.10084
164  2017-11-01 19:09:00     6       38 2453.739 60.94358 16.10084
165  2017-11-01 19:14:00     6       38 2453.739 70.04539 16.10084
166  2017-11-01 19:19:00     6       38 2712.741 72.63943 16.10084
167  2017-11-01 19:24:00     6       38 2712.741 72.63943 16.10084
```

Comment: so, the batch #'s aren't unique? do you just want to separate out contiguous chunks, then?

Comment: I think you need to clarify some things. 
Should it be compared with real time? You save only the last row (according to the time) from the rows with the same batch number (group-wise)?

Comment: yes.. batch No's ranges from 1 to 13.. and it goes like a cyclic.. from 1 to 10, again 1 to 10, sometimes it will be 1 to 13, again 1 to 9, .. I just want to separate the last row alone whenever a batch is completed.

Comment: I don't want to compare with real time or anything. All i want is to take out the row whenever a batch gets completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you still need to clarify a bit but there's no need for a `for` loop:

```
xdf <- read.table("so.dat", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

xdf[cumsum(rle(xdf$batch)$lengths),]
##              event_time batch duration     size       TP       YU
## 8   2017-11-01 06:09:00    10       36 2775.430 70.20428 15.79604
## 17  2017-11-01 06:54:00     1       35 2781.480 70.49287 15.79604
## 35  2017-11-01 08:24:00     2       36 2782.080 69.56226 15.98735
## 44  2017-11-01 09:09:00     3       34 2774.288 70.81388 15.89170
## 58  2017-11-01 10:19:00     4       36 2714.158 69.78924 15.98735
## 67  2017-11-01 11:04:00     5       37 2716.779 70.52529 15.89170
## 84  2017-11-01 12:29:00     6       40 2784.518 70.46044 15.89170
## 92  2017-11-01 13:14:00     7       32 2771.915 71.96498 15.81226
## 99  2017-11-01 13:49:00     8       33 2728.167 70.87549 15.89170
## 111 2017-11-01 14:49:00     9       34 2719.514 72.06226 15.98735
## 119 2017-11-01 15:29:00     1       32 2718.928 72.63943 15.79604
## 127 2017-11-01 16:09:00     2       32 2721.101 72.67185 15.79604
## 138 2017-11-01 17:04:00     3       33 2775.676 72.22438 15.98735
## 145 2017-11-01 17:39:00     4       33 2719.357 73.50519 15.60311
## 154 2017-11-01 18:24:00     5       36 2785.718 73.34306 15.79604
## 166 2017-11-01 19:24:00     6       38 2712.741 72.63943 16.10084
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
# df is the data.frame you provided
new.df <- df %>% mutate(..change = batch != lag(batch)) %>% filter(lead(..change))
```